# Inserting SharePoint content type field into Word document

Tags: document-library, word

How can I dynamically add a SharePoint content type field into a Word document with OpenXML SDK?

Thanks

Comment: SharePoint should already do this for you automatically... Any reason you need to do it yourself?

Comment: Yes. There is not a standard template for the documents. I need to insert this field into all Word documents programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it in an Event Receiver.  Where in the word document do you want to add the Content Type ?  In a Bookmark ?

I might have some sample code I can send you.

Ian.

Comment: Hi Ian. I need to insert the field into footer area.

Comment: What version of Word are you using ?